# How to pass params from view to custom controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, controller

Sorry for rookie question but I want to pass params to controller not related with that view.
I got view with Teams and controller where user adds own favourites teams by marking in Team index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For example pass additional params to link helper like

  `link_to 'fav', addfavoriteteam_user_path(team_id:team.id)`

  and they will be passed to `addfavoriteteam` action of users controller (provided you have routes set for it)
- More RESTful way is to have `favorite` action for teams.
- Or if you want to have a form with checkboxes, you can have it around teams#index, just set form action url to point to another controller

  You probably also want `accepts_nested_attributes_for` for your many-to-many relation model in this case